# functions implementation

Tags: groovy

I have implemented multiple groovy methods for sending different notifications,  but the code breaks-off the functions concept. So i want to rewrite/combine all groovy methods in one single methods so that i can call that one method wherever i need.

Doesn't matter success or failure and i need to pass message as parameter.

```
static void sendSuccessApplicationNotification(p1,p2,p3,p4) {
    def x = Notify(this)
    x.triggerBuild("SUCCESSFUL, application ${p1}:${p2} started properly", "${p3}")
    x.triggerBuild("SUCCESSFUL, application ${p1}:${p2} started properly", "${p4")
}
```

Finally above above should be converted to one method.Checked many articles not getting an exact example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use groovy template engine in your generalized function:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

void triggerBuild(a,b){
    println "${a} >>>> ${b}"
}

void sendNotification(code, Map parms, List nodes) {
    def templates = [
        'appY': 'SUCCESSFUL, application ${app}:${ver} started properly',
        'appN': 'FAILED, application ${app}:${ver} failed to start properly',
        'depY': 'SUCCESSFUL deployment of ${app}:${ver} to ${node}<br>Executed by ${user}',
        'depN': 'FAILED deployment of ${app}:${ver} to ${node}<br>Executed by ${user}'
    ]
    def template = templates[code]
    assert template
    def message = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template).make(parms).toString()
    nodes.each{node->
        triggerBuild(message, node)
    }
}

sendNotification('appY',[app:'myapp', ver:'v123'],['n1','n2'])
```

the code above will output:

```
SUCCESSFUL, application myapp:v123 started properly >>>> n1
SUCCESSFUL, application myapp:v123 started properly >>>> n2
```

Comment: Actually those methods are in jenkins declarative pipeline...Can we do import there.and there are 3 to 4 different message templates...how can we add all in one method?

Comment: yes, you can do import in pipeline. possibly administrator should approve that.

Comment: and all templates you can put in some key-value like config or into a map in code.

Comment: any example please i am not getting an idea as i am layman in groovy